# ImportError: cannot import name 'UserAgentMixin' and werkzeug is installed

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting the following error when I try to run my flask app.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 3, in <module>
    import flask
  File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\PythonData\lib\site-packages\flask\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from werkzeug.exceptions import abort
  File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\PythonData\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\__init__.py", line 151, in <module>
    __import__('werkzeug.exceptions')
  File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\PythonData\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\exceptions.py", line 71, in <module>
    from werkzeug.wrappers import Response
  File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\PythonData\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wrappers\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from .request import PlainRequest
  File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\PythonData\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wrappers\request.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .user_agent import UserAgentMixin
  File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\PythonData\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wrappers\user_agent.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ..useragents import UserAgent
  File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\PythonData\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\useragents.py", line 212, in <module>
    from werkzeug.wrappers import UserAgentMixin  # noqa
ImportError: cannot import name 'UserAgentMixin'
```

I have already installed werkzeug

Comment: Run this command to check whether the module installation is properly done: `pip list | grep <module_name_you_want_to_check>`. Is `UserAgentMixin` a module from werkzeug?

Comment: I did that and nothing happened

Comment: Can you please post the output of that command?  Is `UserAgentMixin` a module from `werkzeug`?